# Screen reader does not read Toast.announce on Firefox browser on Android Tab

Tags: android, firefox, android-tabs, screen-readers, react-toastify

I am having an issue with the screen reader not reading the React toast.announce on fire fox browser on Android Tab.

```
export const announcePageNumber = (currentIndex, screensCount) => {
  Toast.announce(`Page ${currentIndex} of ${screensCount}`);
};

This works for all the browsers (chrome/firefox) on windows/ios, but strangely does not work on firefox browser on Android Tab.

It works fine on Chrome browser on Android Tab.

Seems like an issue with firefox on Android.

Any help would be great!
```